# How to use a while loop that generates 5 random numbers and puts them into a list?

Tags: python, list, while-loop

Need help getting random generated numbers to be put into a list after executed 5 times, preferred through a while loop. My code is only printing one number when i need 5. This is what i have so far, plus im fairly new to python so need some tips.

```
import random

die1 = random.randint(1,6)

result = [ ]

rolls = 0

while rolls < 5:
   ran_die = random.randint(1,6)
   result = ran_die
   rolls = rolls + 1

print(result)

#I want the end results to appear list this. Thank you for help 

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: The `random` tag is irrelevant, you would have the same problem if the assignment was a deterministic value instead of a random one.

Answer (score 0):

You need to append the list as you generate.

```
import random
result = [ ]
rolls = 0
while rolls < 5:
   result.append(random.randint(1,6))
   rolls = rolls + 1

print(result)
```

The better way to do this is:

```
import random
results = [random.randint(1,0) for x in range(5)]
```